# launch a CAT command unix into Dockerfile

Tags: unix, docker, dockerfile, cat

I would like to launch this vagrant command cat(run perfectly!) to provisionning my container with a Dockerfile :

```
# Configure Virtualenvwrapper.
RUN cat <<EOF >> /home/docker/.bashrc
# Virtualenvwrapper configuration.
export WORKON_HOME=\$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=\$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
EOF
```

But I have this error return when I launch my building image docker :

```
 ---> 40f9ed8e187d
Removing intermediate container 85f6c8536520
Step 69 : RUN cat <<EOF >> /home/docker/.bashrc
 ---> Running in dcbb3d441f79
 ---> 78acd9c2e5d5
Removing intermediate container dcbb3d441f79
Step 70 : EXPORT
Unknown instruction: EXPORT
```

**What is the trick for run a cat command unix into image with Dockerfile ?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update [08/03/2022]**: As of `dockerfile/dockerfile:1.4.0`, the [Here-Document support](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/dockerfile/1.4.0/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#here-documents) has been [promoted from labs channel to stable](https://newreleases.io/project/github/moby/buildkit/release/dockerfile/1.4.0). [#2589](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/pull/2589).

You need to use [Docker Buildkit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#buildkit) by setting `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` in your environment, set the [syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#syntax) parser directive to use `dockerfile/dockerfile:1.4.0`, and swap the position of the here delimeter with `cat`. The rest is used like normal.

Dockerfile Example:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.4.0

...

RUN <<EOF cat >> /home/docker/.bashrc
# Virtualenvwrapper configuration.
export WORKON_HOME=\$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=\$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
EOF
```

---

Prior to `dockerfile/dockerfile:1.4.0`, Here-Document syntax was supported in the labs channel `dockerfile/dockerfile:1.3.0-labs` release.

Simply replace version used in the `syntax` parser directive from the above example.

---

Prior to Docker BuildKit labs channel `dockerfile/dockerfile:1.3.0-labs` release, instead of using `cat`, try using `echo` instead!

Turn this shell `cat` example...

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
cat <<EOF > /tmp/example.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
EOF
```

... into this Dockerfile `echo` example!

```
RUN echo -e '\
line 1\n\
line 2\n\
line 3\
' > /tmp/example.txt
```

Note the pair of single quotes (`'`) in the `echo` example.

Also note the `-e` flag for `echo` to support the escaped newlines (`\n`).

**Caution:** Unfortunately, the `-e` flag may or may not be required depending on the version of `echo` your image has installed. For example, the `npm:16` image's `echo` does not require `-e` and actually will print the `-e` along with the single-quoted lines. On the other hand, the `ubuntu:20.04` image's `echo` does require `-e`.

The same example could be written on one line as:
`RUN echo -e 'line 1\nline 2\nline 3' >> /tmp/example.txt`, but I find the above example more readable.

To answer the OP's question, use this:

```
# Configure Virtualenvwrapper.
RUN echo -e '\
# Virtualenvwrapper configuration.\n\
export WORKON_HOME=\$HOME/.virtualenvs\n\
export PROJECT_HOME=\$HOME/Devel\n\
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh\
' >> /home/docker/.bashrc
```

---

**Caution:** The escape character can be redefined by the [`escape` directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#escape). If your Dockerfile has a different escape character set, you'll need to modify the examples accordingly.

Comment: Great update, Build Kit is the way to go.

Comment: Please update link:
https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/reference.md#syntax

Answer (score 32):

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1799#issuecomment-124476047) to an issue posted on Github, this works:

```
RUN echo 'All of your\n\
multiline that you ever wanted\n\
into a dockerfile\n'\
>> /etc/example.conf
```

Comment: This doesn't work if your multilines begin with the `#` character. In this case, you can rearrange the string.  For example, `echo '\[NL]#!/bin/bash\n'` can be rewritten as `echo '#\[NL]!/bin/bash\n'`, where `[NL]` represents a newline in your Dockerfile.

Comment: echo command must be used with -e option to honor newline `\n`  or tab `\t` characters. 
`echo -e` ...

Comment: @Hasan seems debian based shell bash is no need `-e` ?

Answer (score 6):

Dockerfiles are not batch files.   Every line/command is isolated and committed.

Just put the contents into a file and ADD/COPY it.   If you need to customize it, SED it.   Or if you really, really, really want to CAT into a file -- put it in a real batch file, then ADD/COPY it, then RUN it.

Also, less lines = less layers.   70 Steps?   Yowzers.

Comment: Also, you will have to run with the interactive flag on to pickup the .bashrc.   Make some proper execute scripts to ensure ENV vars are set right -vs- the .bashrc "magic" in a container.

Answer (score 5):

You can write it this way:

```
RUN echo "# Virtualenvwrapper configuration." >> /home/docker/.bashrc && \
    echo "export WORKON_HOME=\$HOME/.virtualenvs" >> /home/docker/.bashrc && \
    echo "export PROJECT_HOME=\$HOME/Devel" >> /home/docker/.bashrc && \
    echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> /home/docker/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use below command in place of here document **<<** inside a Dockerfile

```
RUN echo $'[kubernetes] \n\
name=Kubernetes \n\
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64 \n\
enabled=1 \n\
gpgcheck=1 \n\
repo_gpgcheck=1 \n\
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg \n '\
> /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an example straight from Docker documentation:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM alpine
ARG FOO=bar
COPY <<-EOT /app/foo
    hello ${FOO}
EOT
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#example-creating-inline-files

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid here-document syntax for some reason, `printf` is hugely more ergonomical than `echo $'...'` as well as portable to POSIX `sh`.

```
RUN printf '%s\n' > /home/docker/.profile \
    '# Virtualenvwrapper configuration.' \
    'export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs' \
    'export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel' \
    'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh'
```

The single quotes prevent shell interpolation of variables; if you want to expand a variable, use double quotes (though then you'll need to backslash-escape any literal dollar sign, backtick, or backslash).